# Setting Equal to One Another

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why can't I solve this problem by setting the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$? To find the critical points for this problem $f(x,y)=xy-x^3-y^2$ I tried this already and got $0$ as one but I got $-\frac13$ which isn't a value. My question stems from isn't this just a system of equations and we can set the equations equal to each other?

Comment: Hi. You start off by saying "this problem". What is the given problem? To find the critical points of the multivariable function listen below ?

Comment: @Rebellos Yes pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the critical points of the given function $f(x,y)$, one shall solve the following system yielded by the derivatives of the function being equal to zero:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 \Rightarrow y - 3x^2 = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 \Rightarrow x- 2y = 0.$$

Thus, you're asked to solve:

$$\begin{cases} y-3x^2 = 0 \\ x - 2y = 0\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x,y) = \left(0,0\right) 
 \; \text{and} \; (x,y) = \left(\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{12}\right).$$

You can furthermore calculate the second derivative with respect to each variable, to conclude if any of these critical points coincide with an extrema:

$$\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \right|_{x = 0 } = 0, \quad \left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \right|_{x = 1/6 } = 1/6 $$

$$\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right|_{x = 0 } =  \left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \right|_{x = 1/6 } = -2.$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}= 1$$

So, $f$ attains a maximum at the point $(x,y) = (1/6, 1/12)$ with value $f(1/6,1/12)$.

Now, if your question is why you don't yield the same results by solving the system and by just setting $f_x = f_y$, it is because you miss out on a given restriction, which is that both of these partial derivatives are equal to $0$.